# Making Overall App Size Smaller

Tags: ios, app-store, compression, filesize, app-bundle

I just recently talked to an app marketing agency and they are strongly recommending that I find a way to take my 153MB app and somehow get it under the 50MB mark that is the current standard for downloading over a wireless network (3G, 4G, etc.).

I have no idea where to go from here. As far as app size goes, my app is very UI intensive and I have a combination of (mostly) JPGs, PNG's, and a few small videos. I've already run all my jpg's through JPEGmini and as many png's as still looked alright through tinypng.org.

I'm curious if I could somehow "compress" or zip my resources and then unzip them in code to significantly reduce my app size (Before it's installed on the device...I don't care how big it expands to after it's downloaded and installed).

Comment: Maybe try to move your videos to Youtube hosting and access them from you app using Youtube API?

Comment: @AzaFromKaza I do a lot of pausing and replaying certain parts in code, so I don't think streaming from Youtube will be an option.

Comment: You could host them somewhere else and download them from there. The point is just to not have them in the app when it's downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Host the video somewhere else and then downloading them after the app starts for the 1st time (or when they are actually played) maybe the biggest win.  Other small wins would be drawing procedurally as oppose to using images.  What is the combined size of your images, also the combined size of your videos?